# Scene-wide envmap for HDR lighting in three.js

Tags: three.js

I want to try and use an HDR image for my lighting.
I have tried doing

```
var envmap = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "./assets/wooden_lounge_1k.hdr" );
scene.environment = envmap;
```

but all the objects in my scene are black in color.
I have seen some demos but they usually set the `envmap` property in the material for a single object, but I want to have the HDR lighting to be applied on all objects in the scene.

How would I do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a JSFIDDLE website that had some code that would help me. It used the RGBELoader, but it had some extra stuff.

What I did:

```
function setLighting(){

    new RGBELoader()
        .setDataType( THREE.UnsignedByteType )
        .setPath( 'https://threejs.org/examples/textures/equirectangular/' )
        .load( 'royal_esplanade_1k.hdr', function ( texture ) {

        var envMap = pmremGenerator.fromEquirectangular( texture ).texture;

        scene.background = envMap;
        scene.environment = envMap;

        texture.dispose();
        pmremGenerator.dispose();
    })
    var pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator( renderer );
    pmremGenerator.compileEquirectangularShader();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> var envmap = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "./assets/wooden_lounge_1k.hdr" );

You have to load `HDR` textures with `THREE.RGBELoader` (and not with `THREE.TextureLoader`). I suggest you study the following official example for more information:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_texture_hdr

Comment: when I do that, my 3d model is just metallic and I don't see the texture very well. Why would this happen?

Comment: Probably because of bad material settings. Any chance to share a live example that shows your current work of progress?

Comment: I realized that it happened because I used Orthographic Camera. When I used it the texture disappears. This is my question asking about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65821295/texture-of-gltf-object-disappears-when-using-orthographic-camera

Answer (score 1):

Enter `THREE.RGBELoader`
Instead of `THREE.TextureLoader`

I think you should paste this:

```
var envmap = new THREE.RGBELoader().load( "./assets/wooden_lounge_1k.hdr" );
scene.environment = envmap;
```

I hope it works

Comment: when I do that, my 3d model is just metallic and I don't see the texture very well. Why would this happen?